# How to skip install phase in Maven build if I already have this version installed in repo

Tags: maven-2, installation, phase

I have a project that consist of 3 different libraries. When I run install script it takes all libraries from repo and run mvn clean install on them. But this version of library already installed in repo. Is there a way to skip install phase if version in pom.xml equal version in my local repo.

I know that I can use local repo and just set dependencies. But my boss want that our project can build only with public repos and without any our repos.

Comment: Olivier Lamy patched also `https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-73`

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/259907/how-to-do-maven-install-or-deploy-only-without-re-package-re-test

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can bypass like this

```
-Dmaven.install.skip=true
```

---

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>skipInstall</id>
     <activation>
       <property>
         <name>maven.install.skip</name>
         <value>true</value>
       </property>
     </activation>
     <build>
       <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                 <id>default-install</id>
                 <phase>none</phase>
               </execution>
             </executions>
           </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
     </build>
   </profile>
```

Last week Olivier Lamy patched this jira.

[MINSTALL-73](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-73)

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I also noticed that the maven settings.xml file had a warning that the <build> element is 'unrecognized'. I will offer my solution in an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Most maven plugins can be skipped by specifying something like:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>X.Y</version>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

you can also set up build profiles to set properties and use that to determine the value.  for example, running the command: mvn -Pexample would select the "example" profile.  The POM would then contain:

```
...
  <properties>
    <skip.install>false</skip.install>
...
  </properties>

...
    <profile>
      <id>example</id>
      <properties>
        <skip.install>false</skip.install>
      </properties>
    </profile>
...
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>X.Y</version>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${skip.install}</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
```

Using these POM additions, the default behavior for the install plugin will be to perform its default goal, but if the example profile is selected, then the install plugin will skip its goal.

Comment: This is the best solution. But not all plugins have "skip".

Comment: Does install plugin has a skip configuration?

Comment: `maven-install-plugin` does not have `skip` configuration parameter. Provided solution basically doesn't work at all.

Comment: @MichalKalinowski It does as of version 2.4, see [https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-73](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-73)

Answer (score 9):

Using what I learned from the other answers, this was the cleanest result for me.

In my super pom I added a pluginManagement/plugin to disable default-install and default-test phases when the property `deployOnly` is set.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${deployOnly}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${deployOnly}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So on the command line, I can disable install and test phases by adding `-DdeployOnly`.

```
mvn clean install       #build and test everything
mvn deploy -DdeployOnly #just deploy it
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know that I can use local repo and just set dependencies. But my boss want that our project can build only with public repos and without any our repos.

Are you sure you understood correctly what you boss meant? I interpret the above as "don't install third party libraries in your local repository, use only libraries available in public repositories". This is different from "don't use your local repository" which is basically impossible, that's just not how maven works. I'd try to clarify this point.

Apart from that, I don't get the question which is very confusing (what repo are you talking about? What is the install script doing? Why do you call clean install on libraries? etc).

Answer (score 2):

Extending the other answers, from the future.

Maven plugins have a surprisingly high freedom, how do they run. If they want, they can ignore/override the typical pom.xml settings. Furthermore, also the `<configuration><skip>true</skip></configuration>` is only a convention, nothing obligates a plugin to follow it, except that most of them is developed so.

My experiments with the recent problem show, that *both @Cemo's and @MiloshBoroyevich solution should be utilized*, also the plugin requires both to really let us in peace. More concretely, the only working configuration by me was this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your options is to put the deployment to another module. I.e. have one `pom.xml` build the artifact and install it to the local repo, and another `pom.xml` to deploy it. This separation is quite common in larger projects, where the testsuite is sometimes a separate module or even a project, the packaging happens in several stages, etc.

```
- pom.xml - myProject-root - type=pom
  - pom.xml - myProject-artifact - type=jar
  - pom.xml - myProject-deploy - type=pom, does the deployment, skips it's own `install` goal
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid install phase

```
mvn verify deploy:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. **It would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?