# How to skip lifecycle phase in multi maven module

Tags: java, maven-2, build, maven, build-process

I have a maven multi module project which call two sub modules. please note that this child module do not use the  parent markup tag. Now I need to have the deploy phase executed only on one child module but not the other one. Could someone provide any advice on the best way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in this [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html) for `maven deploy plugin`, as well as in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147714/how-to-skip-install-phase-in-maven-build-if-i-already-have-this-version-installed) discussion, you should add the following in the pom of the module you do not want to deploy.

```
        <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>X.Y</version>
           <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Note that not all plugins support this configuration, so do make sure to check the plugin goal configuration! For example `maven-compiler-plugin` uses `skipMain`.

Answer (score 1):

you can go into the directory of the submodule and execute the goal there.

it is also possible to execute a specific module from the 'parent' with the `--also-make` option. see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

multiple-module maven project can specify on which submodule to execute phases with parent pom.xml.

1. Go to where the parent pom.xml is
2. execute: mvn --projects [target-module-artifactId] [phase/goal]. For example: mvn --projects submodule1 deploy